# Minikube Accessing Images Added With Registry Addon

Tags: macos, docker, minikube, docker-registry

I’ve followed the instructions outlined on [this page](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#4-pushing-to-an-in-cluster-using-registry-addon) and pushed a local image to a local 3 node Minikube cluster with the registry add-on enabled and the cluster started with insecure-registry flag, but I get the following error when I try to create a Pod with the image:

> Normal   Pulling    9m18s (x4 over 10m)  kubelet            Pulling image "192.168.99.100:5000/myapp:v1”
> Warning  Failed     9m18s (x4 over 10m)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "192.168.99.100:5000/myapp:v1”: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://192.168.99.100:5000/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Any advice on resolving this would be greatly appreciated

My Minikube (v1.23.2) is on macOS (Big Sur 11.6) using the VirtualBox driver.  It is a three node cluster. My Docker Desktop version is (20.10.8)

These are the steps I followed:

1. Get my cluster’s VMs’ IP range - 192.168.99.0/24
2. Added the following entry to my Docker Desktop config:

```
insecure-registries": [
    "192.168.99.0/24"
  ]
```

3. Started Minikube with insecure registries flag:

```
$ minikube start —insecure-registry=“192.168.99.0/24”
```

4. Run:

```
$ minikube addons enable registry
```

5. Tagged the image I want to push:

```
$ docker tag docker.io/library/myapp:v1 $(minikube ip):5000/myapp:v1
```

6. Pushed the image:

```
$ docker push $(minikube ip):5000/myapp:v1
```

The push works ok - when I exec onto the registry Pod I can see the image in the filesystem. However, when I try to create a Pod using the image, I get the error mentioned above.

My Pod manifest is:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: myapp
  name: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - image: 192.168.99.100:5000/myapp:v1
    name: myapp
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by deleting the cluster and recreating it using the insecure-registry flag from the start - originally I had created the cluster, stopped it, and then started it again with the insecure-registry flag. For some reason this didn't work, but starting it for the first time with the flag did.

If you're going to be creating clusters with the registry addon a lot, it might be worth adding the flag permanently to your config. Replace the IP with your cluster's subnet:

```
$ minikube config set insecure-registry "192.168.99.0/24"
```